# Setting setMinimumTrackImage of UISlider corners with different color

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I am currently working on a set of problem where I need to set the right and left corner of the UISlider with different color.

Currently, this is what I have got so far.

[image]

If you notice, on the right side if I don't alter with maximum track image I get the result, but when I start altering the minimum track image to have some color variation for certain placement of x, I don't get the rounded shape. I tried to visualize it on the Debug View Hierarchy and it does fall under the same layer.

Below is the code as of what I am trying to achieve.

```
    let color = UIColor.green
    color.setFill()
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.clip(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: image.size.height), mask: image.cgImage!)
    context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: image.size.height))
    let coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

Is there anything I am missing here?